# Cannot Access Session From ASPX to Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

I have set session in my presentation layer and I am trying to get that session value from my Class Library using the below code

```
var dt= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DT"];
```

But Object reference error is showing

Comment: For same thread System.Web.HttpContext.Current will never be null Can u share more information

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring in a class library .dll

Make sure you have added `System.Web` assembly reference in a class library project

In case, if you have created your own custom HttpHandler, please implement <kbd>[IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx)</kbd> interface to read session values